# Solving double integral with $0<x<y<5$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let D be the region of the $xy$ plane where $0 < x < y < 5$. Calculate
$$\int\int_D (x^2y-y^2)dxdy$$
I am familiar with double integrals, but I have never seen the bounds of integration given like this. I don't know what to put for the bounds. I assume it is $0<y<5$ for $y$, but $x<y$  so 5 can't be the bound for $x,$ right? Maybe I'm wrong. Nevertheless, I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: The Bounds (or End Points) for the Outer Integral are ($0$ & $5$) , while the Inner Integral has the Bounds (or End Points) ($0$ & $y$) , where the Overall Area of Integration will be Triangular !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image has the Diagonal line $y=x$ , & the gray shaded area is $x<y$ , & the other unshaded area is $x>y$

The Purple shaded area is $D$ (the triangular Part) where we want the Integration.

[image: Area]

The Bounds (or End Points) for the Outer Integral are [$y=0$ & $y=5$]
The Inner Integral has the Bounds (or End Points) [$x=0$ & $x=y$]
$D$ is the Overall Area of Integration which will be Triangular

Now it is straight-forward to get the Integral.

$$ \int \int_D (x^2y-y^2) dx dy = \int_0^5 \int_0^y (x^2y-y^2) dx dy $$

$$ \int \int_D (x^2y-y^2) dx dy = \int_0^5 [x^3y/3-xy^2]_0^y dy $$

$$ \int \int_D (x^2y-y^2) dx dy = \int_0^5 [y^3y/3-yy^2] dy $$

$$ \int \int_D (x^2y-y^2) dx dy = \int_0^5 [y^4/3-y^3] dy $$

$$ \int \int_D (x^2y-y^2) dx dy = [y^5/15-y^4/4]_0^5 $$

$$ \int \int_D (x^2y-y^2) dx dy = [5^5/15-5^4/4] $$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!